# Set a command to a variable in bash script problem

Tags: bash

Trying to run a command as a variable but I am getting strange results

Expected result "1" :

```
grep -i nosuid /etc/fstab | grep -iq nfs 
echo $?
1
```

Unexpected result as a variable command:

```
cmd="grep -i nosuid /etc/fstab | grep -iq nfs"
$cmd
echo $?
0
```

It seems it returns 0 as the command was correct not actual outcome. How to do this better ?

Comment: [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only execute exactly one command stored in a variable. The pipe is passed as an argument to the first `grep`.

Example

```
$ printArgs() { printf %s\\n "$@"; }
# Two commands. The 1st command has parameters "a" and "b".
# The 2nd command prints stdin from the first command.
$ printArgs a b | cat
a
b
$ cmd='printArgs a b | cat'
# Only one command with parameters "a", "b", "|", and "cat".
$ $cmd
a
b
|
cat
```

> How to do this better?

Don't execute the command using variables.
Use a function.

```
$ cmd() { grep -i nosuid /etc/fstab | grep -iq nfs; }
$ cmd
$ echo $?
1
```

#### Solution to the actual problem

I see three options to your actual problem:

- Use a `DEBUG` trap and the `BASH_COMMAND` variable inside the trap.
- Enable bash's history feature for your script and use the `hist` command.
- Use a function which takes a command string and executes it using `eval`.

Regarding your comment on the last approach: You only need *one* function. Something like

```
execAndLog() {
    description="$1"
    shift
    if eval "$*"; then
        info="PASSED: $description: $*"
        passed+=("${FUNCNAME[1]}")
    else
       info="FAILED: $description: $*"
       failed+=("${FUNCNAME[1]}")
    done
}
```

You can use this function as follows

```
execAndLog 'Scanned system' 'grep -i nfs /etc/fstab | grep -iq noexec'
```

The first argument is the description for the log, the remaining arguments are the command to be executed.

Comment: `Don't execute the command using variables. Use a function.` should be in bold letters :-)!

Comment: The reason I was doing it this way was because I wanted to print the command used in another variable... basically build a log of the command  echo "Failed: ${cmd}" ..

Comment: @MikeQ If you give a bit more explanation on what you actually need we might be able to help you. Is printing failed commands (that don't have to be stored inside variables) all you want to do? Edit your question.

Comment: FYI : I added "bonus question" to my question to show what I'm doing ... basically I was thinking it would be nicer to just use a variable inside of the  "info" variable ..

Comment: @Socowi since you didn't respond to my sample code, I removed it from the question to avoid confusion for others. I also am not entirely sold on making a function for every command. I have a script that checks one thing and returns pass or fail, to create an additional 100 functions just to run a one liner seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @MikeQ I responded by adding the three approaches at the end. Seems like they were not explained sufficiently enough though. You only need *one* function. I added the function and an example that should be equivalent to the code you removed from your answer (except that I used lowercase variable names because that's the recommended style).

Answer (score 1):

using `bash -x` or `set -x` will allow you to see what bash executes:

```
> cmd="grep -i nosuid /etc/fstab | grep -iq nfs"
> set -x
> $cmd
+ grep -i nosuid /etc/fstab '|' grep -iq nfs
```

as you can see your pipe `|` is passed as an argument to the first grep command.

Comment: Gotcha .. that was the issue  ...  I guess I have to defer to the previous comment on proper usage  ...

Comment: yes indeed; my answer is a complement; not a replacement of the answer of @socowi :)

Comment: I appreciate your help